# Send Sample Message to LUIS?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

To create part of a test, how can I use C# to send a single message to my LUIS app endpoint and get a result? Instead of using the interactive console at http://luis.ai, I want to send my own message to evaluate the response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

LUIS provide an [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f) that you can call. For C#, you might want to take advantage of the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/CognitiveServices/dataPlane/Language/LUIS).

Comment: I downloaded a .zip of the .NET SDK, Solution fails to load. "...\Cognitive-Common-Windows\SampleUserControlLibrary\SampleUserControlLibrary.csproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path..." Code is massively missing.

Comment: Is there a way to get logs of communication for a given LUIS app?

Answer (score 0):

And in case one needs to mimic or mock the Luis calls (or for that matter, any URL call) , one can use NOCK

https://github.com/node-nock/nock